# Selecting most recent data and grouping by a column

Tags: sql, vertica

My data in the table look like this:

```
appName bytes  timestamp
-------- --------
app1   1   10
app2   2   20
app1   3   30
app2   4   40
app1   5   50
```

I want the following output:

```
app1   5   50
app2   4   40
```

i.e. I want the most recent (by timestamp) data with no duplicates.

So far I've following query:

```
select appName,bytes, max(ts) 
from myTable 
group by appName,bytes
```

But the above query gives me two rows for app1 and app2. I want only one row for each app and it corresponds to the most recent timestamp.

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `Max` timestamp per `appname` and `join` the result back to table using `appname` and `timestamp`. Try this.

```
SELECT a.appname,
       a.bytes,
       a.timestamp
FROM   yourtable a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(timestamp) timestamp,
                    appname
             FROM   yourtable)B
         ON a.appname = b.appname
            AND a.timestamp = b.timestamp
            AND a.appname = b.appname
```

or use [**`Analytic Function`**](https://my.vertica.com/docs/CE/5.1.0/HTML/index.htm#10967.htm)

```
SELECT a.appname,
       a.bytes,
       a.timestamp
FROM  (SELECT *,
              Row_number() OVER(partition BY appname
                  ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn,          
       FROM   yourtable) a
WHERE  rn = 1
```